# Slot utilisation of Copy, Load and Export Operation on Flat Rate Pricing for Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Will Copy, Load and Export  (free operation) use allocated slots in flat-rate pricing ?

List of free operation below.
The three listed above should be the one that uses significant resource
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that Flat-rate pricing is applicable only to query costs, not for storage which all three mentioned by you operations deal with.
So I think, they (Copy, Load and Export) do not use allocated slots as no querying involved